# how to show 'for' loop progress Indicator in flutter

Tags: flutter, loops, flutter-circularprogressindicator

I have a loop that prints "hello world"  100 times. so what i want is to show progress Indicator which shows the loop progress..
for example: if the loop printed 50 time from total 100 time the progress Indicator should be at 50 percent..

Comment: use `LinearProgressInditacor` / `CircularProgressIndicator` then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @pskink mentioned in the comments, a `LinearProgressIndicator` or `CircularProgressIndicator` should do the trick. Do go into a bit more detail, you can store the progress after each iteration (or every so many iterations depending on your needs), and if you use your widget's state for it, a rebuild should automatically trigger and rebuild the progress indicator with the new value each time. That could look a bit like:

```dart
// inside the State
double progress = 0.0;

doTheLoop() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    print('Hello world');
    setState(() => progress = i/100);
  }
}

build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(children: [
    Container(
      // the progress indicator updates when the progress variable in the state updates, since a rebuild is triggered
      child: LinearProgressIndicator(
        progress: progress,
      );
    ),
    
    // press the button to start the loop
    ElevatedButton(
      child: Text('Start loop'),
      onPressed: doTheLoop,
    ),
  ],),
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here Direct `Setstate` not work because for loop execute as soon as possible.So we add 100 millisecond time delay for visual progress

```
await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100));
```

**Linewar Widget**

```
LinearProgressIndicator(
                minHeight: 25,
                value: _value,
                color: _color,
                semanticsValue: (_value * 100).toString(),
                semanticsLabel: (_value * 100).toString(),
              )
```

**while Press loopbutton**

```
  Future<void> loop() async {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {

      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100));
      var element = i;
      print(element);
      setState(() {
        _value = element / 100;
        print(_value);
      });
      if (element < 5 && element > 0)
        _color = Colors.red;
      else if (element < 25 && element > 5)
        _color = Colors.cyan;
      else if (element < 50 && element > 25)
        _color = Colors.lightGreenAccent;
      else if (element < 75 && element > 50)
        _color = Colors.lightGreen;
      else if (element < 100 && element > 75) _color = Colors.green;
    }
  }
```

[image]

**Without Streamcontroller** [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=0aff2d4c08b2e1e34277da3551ee21cb)

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: "/",
      routes: {
        "/": (context) => Home(),
      },
      title: _title,
      // home: ,
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("title")),
      body: const Center(
        child: MyStatelessWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

var _color = Colors.black;
var _value = 0.0;

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatelessWidget> createState() => _MyStatelessWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatelessWidgetState extends State<MyStatelessWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Positioned(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      strokeWidth: 4,
                      value: _value,
                      color: _color,
                    ),
                  ),
                  top: 0,
                  left: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  bottom: 0,
                ),
                Positioned(
                  child: Text(
                    (_value * 100).toStringAsFixed(1),
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                  ),
                  top: 25,
                  left: 10,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            height: 75,
            width: 75,
          ),
          Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                minHeight: 25,
                value: _value,
                color: _color,
                semanticsValue: (_value * 100).toString(),
                semanticsLabel: (_value * 100).toString(),
              )),
          Text(
            (_value * 100).toStringAsFixed(1),
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    loop();
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.not_started_outlined,
                    size: 45,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: Icon(Icons.stop, size: 45),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> loop() async {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
      // if (!stream.isClosed) stream.sink.addStream(Stream.value(i));
      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100));
      var element = i;
      print(element);
      setState(() {
        _value = element / 100;
        print(_value);
      });
      if (element < 5 && element > 0)
        _color = Colors.red;
      else if (element < 25 && element > 5)
        _color = Colors.cyan;
      else if (element < 50 && element > 25)
        _color = Colors.lightGreenAccent;
      else if (element < 75 && element > 50)
        _color = Colors.lightGreen;
      else if (element < 100 && element > 75) _color = Colors.green;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {}
}
```

This Sample .Here use `streamcontroller` .so  using stream controller mange the progress like pause or stop the progress.

**SampleCode** [Dart pad Live code](https://dartpad.dev/?id=30db667200661d79552611c1f5360d65)

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: "/",
      routes: {
        "/": (context) => Home(),
      },
      title: _title,
      // home: ,
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("title")),
      body: const Center(
        child: MyStatelessWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

var _color = Colors.black;
var _value = 0.0;

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatelessWidget> createState() => _MyStatelessWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatelessWidgetState extends State<MyStatelessWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Positioned(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      strokeWidth: 4,
                      value: _value,
                      color: _color,
                    ),
                  ),
                  top: 0,
                  left: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  bottom: 0,
                ),
                Positioned(
                  child: Text(
                    (_value * 100).toStringAsFixed(1),
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                  ),
                  top: 25,
                  left: 10,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            height: 75,
            width: 75,
          ),
          Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                minHeight: 25,
                value: _value,
                color: _color,
                semanticsValue: (_value * 100).toString(),
                semanticsLabel: (_value * 100).toString(),
              )),
          Text(
            (_value * 100).toStringAsFixed(1),
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    loop();
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.not_started_outlined,
                    size: 45,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    stream.close();
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.stop, size: 45),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> loop() async {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
      if (!stream.isClosed) stream.sink.addStream(Stream.value(i));
      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100));
    }
    // List.generate(100, (index) => index + 1).forEach((element) async {
    //   if (!stream.isClosed) stream.sink.addStream(Stream.value(element));
    //   await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    // });
  }

  // late StreamController<int> stream;
  StreamController<int> stream = StreamController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    stream.stream.listen((element) {
      print(element);
      setState(() {
        _value = element / 100;
        print(_value);
      });
      if (element < 5 && element > 0)
        _color = Colors.red;
      else if (element < 25 && element > 5)
        _color = Colors.cyan;
      else if (element < 50 && element > 25)
        _color = Colors.lightGreenAccent;
      else if (element < 75 && element > 50)
        _color = Colors.lightGreen;
      else if (element < 100 && element > 75) _color = Colors.green;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
 class testwidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const testwidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _test createState() => _test();
}
```

---

```
class _test extends State<testwidget> {

  StreamController loopValueStram=new StreamController();
  var loopProgress=0.0;
  static const  max=100;


  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    loopValueStram.stream.listen((event) {
      setState(() {
        loopProgress=event;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('test'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child:Column(
            children: [
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  loop();
                },
                child: Text("Start loop ${(loopProgress*100).toInt()}%"),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10,),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Visibility(
                    visible:loopProgress>0,
                    child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                      value: loopProgress.toDouble(),
                      semanticsLabel: "Progress",
                      minHeight: 40,
                    )),
              )
            ],
          )
        )
    );
  }

  Future<void> loop() async {
    for(int i=0;i<=100;i++){
      loopValueStram.sink.add(i/100);
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));// this line is to slowdown itération so we can see linear pregression well
    }
  }

}
```